# MySQL query 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

in simple I try do that in PhpMyAdmin:

> update wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_posts.id where
>
> wp_posts.post_name=articles.image
>
> AND wp_posts.post_type=attachment
>
> AND wp_postmeta.meta_key=_thumbnail_id

by this MySQL query:

```
update wp_postmeta m
join articles a on (m.post_id = a.id)
join wp_posts p on (m.post_id = p.ID)
set m.meta_value = p.ID
where p.post_name=a.image
AND a.image != NULL
AND p.post_type='attachment'
AND m.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

it's work but 0 rows affected!
anyone can help?

Comment: Help with what? There is no such rows, so none were updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries with Andomar's answer. Using joins with update and delete statements is not good.

It should be something like

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta m SET m.meta_value = (SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p, articles a 
WHERE m.post_id=p.ID AND m.post_id = a.id AND a.image IS NOT NULL 
   AND p.post_type='attachment' AND p.post_name=a.image) 
WHERE m.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

**BACKUP FIRST!** I didn't test this.

If doesn't work try to execute a select query if you can select them. If it doesn't select (and probably it won't) please check the structure of your query corresponding to your design.

```
SELECT m.meta_value, (SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p, articles a 
WHERE m.post_id=p.ID AND m.post_id = a.id AND a.image IS NOT NULL 
   AND p.post_type='attachment' AND p.post_name=a.image)  AS pID
FROM wp_postmeta m
WHERE m.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

Also try your first query too

```
SELECT m.meta_value, p.ID AS pID FROM wp_postmeta m
INNER JOIN articles a on (m.post_id = a.id)
INNER JOIN wp_posts p on (m.post_id = p.ID)
WHERE p.post_name=a.image
AND a.image IS NOT NULL
AND p.post_type='attachment'
AND m.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

Try to play with/modify the select queries to find out the problem.

Comment: No. MySQL has no problem with Joins in Update and Delete statements.

Comment: It still againsts logic. When you select something you use joins and you get one result as a set. When you use update or delete if you use join and merge tables, the result will still be applied as seperately to the tables. Subqueries still better, even if DBMS supports jins, it is better for human readability and not making mistakes and also portability.

Comment: You are right that you have to ensure that there is one row selected from the table to be deleted or updated. MySQL has some limitations though on what you put in the `WHERE` conditions of Update/Delete statements (not in your example, that is fine). And also performance issues. So, it's usually better to use Joins - with MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube Performance is better with joins than with subqueries, I agree that. Btw, Ansi does not support deleting with jins, check the format at section 13.6, http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: @Loai, please check the corresponding values to the fields. For example are you sure that a.image is not null everywhere you want to delete? Or m.meta_key is really equals to '_thumbnail_id' everywhere? Or p.post_type? Or is there joins as stated? The query is ok, the rest should be about matching by given statement so please check the statement if the values are really ok.

Comment: the values is oky, i have more than 6000 rows

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
AND a.image != NULL
```

always evaluates to `unknown`.  And `where` clause filters out rows which are not `true`.  So a `where` filters out both `unknown` and `false`.  Try this instead:

```
AND a.image is not null
```

See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) for more information.

Comment: In that case, can you post some example data for which you'd expect your query to produce results?